# How to implement watershed segmentation with maximum volume

Tags: python, volume, watershed

I used `skimage.morphology.watershed` to get the initial segmentation of a series image. However, I would like to set a maximum volume to the segmented region.

For example, I have a matrix `M`:

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.morphology import watershed
from scipy.ndimage.morphology import distance_transform_edt

M = np.zeros((30, 30))
M[5, 5] = 1
M[25, 25] = 2
M_edt = distance_transform_edt(M==0)
M_seg = watershed(M_edt, markers=M)  # |--> maximum pixels in one region should be, for example, 20 pixels.
```

Result:
[segmentation with watershed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZByJm.png)

Actually, I worked in 3D, but the principle in 2D should also be applied. Thanks for your any help in advance!